# MessageBox displaying twice rather once

Tags: vb.net, infragistics, messagebox

I've got an `UltraComboBox` control on my form, which uses the following code.

```
Private Sub cmbType_ValueChanged(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) Handles cmbType.ValueChanged
  If cmbType.Value <> "" Then
       If cmbType.Value = "Custom Template" Then
           Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [System Settings]", con)
           Dim ds As New DataSet
           Da.Fill(ds)

           If ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("enableTemplate") = False Then
               MessageBox.Show("Custom Templates have not been enabled at system level.", "Cannot Add Custom Template", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
               cmbType.Value = ""
           End If
       ElseIf cmbType.Value = "Default Template"
           ' ...
       End If
  End If
End Sub
```

The issue I'm getting is that after closing the `MessageBox`, it sets the value to "", then iterates the code, then, for some reason, does it again but the value is back to "Custom Template", so the `MessageBox` shows for a second time.

Is there something wrong with the code, or is there an easier way of doing this?

***EDIT***

The following has not affected it, so I'm assuming that I've not interpreted @Steve's suggestion correctly.

```
If ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("enableTemplate") = False Then
    MessageBox.Show("Custom Templates have not been enabled at system level.", "Cannot Add Custom Templates", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    RemoveHandler cmbType.ValueChanged, AddressOf cmbType_ValueChanged
    cmbType.Value = ""
    AddHandler cmbType.ValueChanged, AddressOf cmbType_ValueChanged
End If
```

***EDIT 2***

As per @HansPasssant's suggestion:

```
If ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("enableTemplate") = False Then
    Me.BeginInvoke(Sub() MessageBox.Show("Custom Templates have not been enabled at system level.", "Cannot Add Custom Templates", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information))
    RemoveHandler cmbType.ValueChanged, AddressOf cmbType_ValueChanged
    cmbType.Value = ""
    AddHandler cmbType.ValueChanged, AddressOf cmbType_ValueChanged
End If
```

This still shows the `MessageBox` twice.

Comment: If you don't set the combo to a blank string, does the message box still shows itself two times?

Comment: is there something like `SelectedIndexChanged(...` instead `ValueChanged`?

Comment: @Steve No. If I don't set it to a blank string it only shows once. I need it to show a blank string, though. Is there another way around it?

Comment: @nelek This isn't a regular `ComboBox`, events like that don't exist for the `Infragistics` controls.

Comment: You could try to disconnect the event handler until you set the combo to blank and then reconnect it

Comment: @Steve See edit. I'm guessing what I've done is not what you meant, since this shows it twice, too?

Comment: No that's was exactly what I meant. I would check if somewhere you set that value back. For example you could set a breakpoint in this event handler and check (on the second call) the stack trace to see if you can get some hint about the code flow that leads to this second call.

Comment: Jerking the focus away in an event that fires on a focusing event is apt to cause this problem.  Usually fixed by delaying the display of the message box with Me.BeginInvoke().

Comment: @Steve Nope, searched the full document, too. There are no references to `cmbType.Value = "Custom Template"` anywhere but this subroutine.

Comment: @HansPassant Do you have any examples of how this would be done? I've just had a go and I'm not really understanding how to use it and the docs isn't really helping.

Comment: Me.BeginInvoke(Sub() MessageBox.Show("message"))

Comment: @HansPassant Hmm... That still shows it twice, as I added into the question (Edit 2). Not sure what's going wrong.

Comment: What version of Infragistics controls are you using? There was a bug https://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/27620.aspx

Comment: @Steve In the References is says `Infragistics.Win.v5.1` as the Reference Name, with 5.1.20051.37 as the Version

Comment: It is a very old version. Probably it is a bug that has been fixed because I am unable to reproduce it with version 15.2

Comment: @Steve Where am I able to download a newer version? Or is this not possible, without buying them?

Comment: It is a paid suite. After all these years I think you need to buy it or search their website if there is a patch for your version released after the 20051.37. But what about changing the logic of your code? Do not load the invalid value in the combo if the custom templates are not allowed. How do you load this combo?

Comment: @Steve I had it that way originally, where it didn't load this value, but the end user, for reasons only they know, are adamant they don't want that, it must load all values and then operate as it is above. When loading it I just declare a new `DataTable` and dynamically add rows in the `Form_Load` event.

Comment: Then, if you can't find a proper fix or change the mind of your customer, I suggest to revert to a normal combo. It doesn't seem that you need the extra functionality of an UltraCombo or UltraComboEditor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a bug in `UltraCombo`, as appears to be the case, you have 2 options:

1) Use a regular `ComboBox` to do the same thing - Although, it will look different so the end user may not be totally happy with this.

2) Alternatively, if you don't have lots of items in the `DropDownList`, you could use `RadioButtons` in a `GroupBox` to do the same thing.

Then, if the Custom Template `RadioButton.Checked = True`, run the same checks and output the `MessageBox`.

Without upgrading the controls, there really isn't a lot you can do about this, so I guess these are your only two options.

Comment: Thanks, I did the `RadioButton` idea like you said.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the value of the combo in ValueChanged event you are forcing this event to fire again. As you are in the middle of the event this may lead to strange results as in your case. What you can do is turn of the events of UltraCombo, through its [EventManager](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2013.2/CLR4.0/html/Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.v13.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraCombo~EventManager.html), just before set its value, by setting:

UltraCombo.EventManager.AllEventsEnabled = false

Then, after value is set, set all events enabled back to true

Comment: I'd already changed the layout and have it working as @David suggested, but thanks, if it happens again I'll give this a try.